# Create trigger in CREATE DATABASE stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, dynamic-sql

We have a stored procedure that creates a database for each of our customers. This stored procedure runs in the context of master. A database name is passed in as a parameter to the stored procedure.

I am trying to modify the stored procedure to add a trigger to a table. I understand the stored procedure must switch to the new database to create triggers, so have appended the following to the stored procedure:

```
SET @str = ('USE ' + QUOTENAME (@db_name) + ' GO
CREATE TRIGGER ...')
EXEC (@str);
```

I get the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>
> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Now I assume the second error is a consequence of the first, but I am blowed if I can work out how to switch databases in the stored procedure in order to create the triggers.

We are using SQL Server 2019. How do I create triggers in a create database stored procedure?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48159/how-to-create-a-trigger-in-a-different-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to execute statement one after another.

```sql
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @db_name SYSNAME = 'YourDBName'
SET @str = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME (@db_name)
EXEC (@str)
SET @str = 'CREATE TRIGGER ...' 
exec (@str);
```

For completeness, as mentioned by @DaleK, adding [the approach mentioned by Aaron Bertnard in the Stackexchange link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48159/how-to-create-a-trigger-in-a-different-database)

```sql
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @db_name SYSNAME = 'master'
SET @str = 'EXEC '+  @db_name + '..sp_executesql @stmt=N''CREATE PROCEDURE usp_test AS SELECT 1;''' 
exec (@str);
```

Comment: I tried that @Venkataraman R. Problems arose around `CREATE TRIGGER` having to be the first statement in a batch. If I preceded `CREATE TRIGGER` with `GO` then I lost db_name

Comment: @Vague, yes. you have to execute them in order, as mentioned. Or you have to use `sp_Executesql` as mentioned by @DaleK